# how to fix align issue on tabbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want like this tab bar, my tab ugly, and also how to add divider like this?

[image: please check]

but I tried tab bar,
[image]

**my build method**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: DashboardAppBar(),
          body: TabBarView(physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), children: [
            dashboardGridView(),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ]),
        ));
  }
```

**dashboardGridView() class**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class DashboardAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const DashboardAppBar({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
       ...
```

**I added tabbar on AppBar bottom property**

```
        bottom: TabBar(
           isScrollable: true,
            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
            controller: controller,
            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
```

**border is not right place,how to fix?**

```
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 4,
                  color: Color(0xFF646464),
                ),
                insets: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 8,
                    bottom: 4)),
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
            tabs: [
```

**first tab**

```
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                text: 'Category',
              ),
```

**second tab**

```
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
                text: 'My Enquiries',
              ),
```

**I added button her? Is it right?**

```
              Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: RaisedButton.icon(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.speaker),
                        label: Text(
                          'Promotions',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),),)),]));}
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(130.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),`